# import css file into es6 returns string instead of object

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, import

## TL;DR

I'm importing a css file into a typescript module, but the import resolves to a string instead of an object. Can anyone tell me why I don't get an object??

## Example

```ts
// preview.ts

import test from './src/assets/test.theme.css';

// also tried this:
// import * as test from './src/assets/test.theme.css';

console.log('typeof test: ', typeof test);
console.log(test);
```

**Console output**
[image: screenshot]

## Detailed explanation

Actually, I'm trying to set up a [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) for my Angular12 component library.

In order to provide various themes, I want to use the [`@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme`](https://github.com/etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme) plugin, which in its documentation refers to the inline loader syntax of Webpack.

```
import myTheme from '!!style-loader?injectType=lazyStyleTag!css-loader!./assets/my-theme.css';
```

When applying this to my code my browser console started to complain

> Error: myTheme.use is not a function

During my research I recognized that the imported stylesheet is not an evaluated javascript object, but instead it is provided as a string containing the sourcecode generated by the style-loader.

I also recognized, that this issue is not specific to the style-loader, but also occurs for all other loaders, e.g. css-loader, raw-loader, etc.

This issue is also not related to inline loader syntax, as it also shows up with loaders being defined in a minimalistic webpack config.

**Environment:**

- Angular 12
- Webpack 5

## Reproduction

I have set up a [GIT repo reproducing the issue](https://github.com/rb-mwindh/angular12-webpack5-inline-loader-repro).

The readme file explains the repro and the issue.

Comment: Why would you do this with Angular?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to setup a Storybook for my Angular component library.
I wanted to use the [Storybook addon "cssVariablesTheme"](https://github.com/etchteam/https://github.com/etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme) which proposes to use the style-loader lazyStyleTag feature to enable and disable themes at runtime.

While following the documentation, I hit weird issues. When further drilling into the issue, I found out, that it also happens with the described simple use case.
Btw: Storybook dynamically generates a webpack config based on my angular.json settings.

Comment: Maybe it could be a simple import error try `import * as test from './src/assets/test.theme.css'`

Comment: Have you tried this `import './style.css'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my issue solved!

### Analysis

The main issue here is the webpack configuration generated by the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package. I was able to analyze it by debugging a fresh angular12 application (you can check it out [here](https://github.com/rb-mwindh/angular12-webpack5-inline-loader-repro)).

By setting a break-point at `/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js`, function: `generateWebpackConfig(...)`, I could inspect the final `webpackConfig` object  in the debugger.

The relevant [rule](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulerules) looks like this:

> **The important part here is the rule setting the module type to `asset/source`, instructing webpack not to evaluate the loader's result.**

[image: webpackConfig object]

### Solution concept 1: inline loader

With the help of [alexander-kait](https://github.com/alexander-akait) and his great hints at [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12531),
I was able to find an inline-loader syntax that overrides webpack's module declaration:

```
import Test from 'test.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!!!style-loader?injectType=lazyStyleTag!css-loader!./test.css';

console.log(typeof Test); // output: object
console.log(Test); // output: Object { use: () => void, unuse: () => void }
Test.use(); // this should usually be called by a theme switcher...
```

I'm not really sure about the url pattern here, as it seems to be an undocumented feature, but I assume that it's something like `<query-pattern>.webpack[<module-type>]!=!<loaders><query>`.

However, since this is an undocumented feature, I was rather reluctant to use it.

### Solution concept 2: webpackConfig customization

Since I'm in a storybook context, I decided to customize the webpack configuration according to the [storybook documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config).

My solution requires to set up a naming convention (e.g. `*.theme.css`).

```
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {

    // exclude *.theme.css from the *.css ruleset
    config.module.rules.find(rule => '.css'.match(rule.test)).exclude = [ /\.(?:theme\.css)$/i ];

    // add a rule for *.theme.css
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(?:theme\.css)$/i,
      use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'lazyStyleTag' } },
        'css-loader',
      ],
    });
  },
};
```

With these rules in place, I can now simply do the following:

```
// preview.js

import LightTheme from './light.theme.css';
import DarkTheme from './dark.theme.css';

setupThemeSwitcher(LightTheme, DarkTheme);
```

> *Please note that the `setupThemeSwitcher` function is just pseudocode merely there for the example. In reality I'm using the [@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme) addon...*

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistake in your `Webpack` config. You have nested `rules` property, instead you should have `use`:

```js
{
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  }
```

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

Comment: The webpack config is just an excerpt. My actual webpack config is generated by Storybook based on my angular.json settings.
My actual issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570350/import-test-from-css-loader-test-css-returns-string), but no-one bothered even reading it... maybe I was not clear enough with my question... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I have to revert my last statement. My issue has NOT been resolved by @Akxe's comment.
Now my import statement (`import * as test from '...'`) resolves to an object, but it's still not correct.

I have set up a [GIT Repo to reproduce the issue](https://github.com/rb-mwindh/angular12-webpack5-inline-loader-repro). The `readme.md` file explains the repro and the issue.

It looks like Webpack is not executing/evaluating the return value of the loader.

Btw. this is not just the case with the css-loader. The result stays the same for raw-loader, sass-loader, style-loader, etc.

> My final goal is to lazily load my theme files into a storybook.
> I try to follow the documentation of the [@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-> theme](https://github.com/etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with storybook and this extension, except l’m loading .scss files.
I simply adapted solution 2 to suit my .scss case and it works like a charm.
I couldn’t make solution 1 to work, but as stated, it sounds hacky whereas solution 2 is cleaner in my opinion.
Thanks a lot for sharing this solution, I was struggling for hours.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30500703)